# Perl - Changing the color of a link using HTML::Element

Tags: html, perl

I'm trying to change the color of the link text in a link to yellow on a page that another script (not controlled by me) generates.  More specifically, I'm searching for specific text in two tables on this page.  Once I find the text (which are hyperlinks) I want to change their color to yellow.

I am using HTML::Element and I can find the text easily.  The problem is, there is no specified link color, so the links use the default value of blue.  I am trying to add the HTML element of font color to the  tag but I'm not having much luck.

If I try using something like (where "$a" is the HTML::Element object for the link I'm trying to edit):

```
$a->attr("font color", "yellow");
```

It adds the attribute but doesn't change the text color of the link content.

if I try something like:

```
my $content = $a->content;
$content->attr("font color", "yellow");
```

That only adds the text

```
<font color=yellow>
```

to the content without, again, changing the actual content text color.

Trying to splice it in doesn't work either.

I finally hit upon this:

```
 my $yellowFont = HTML::Element->new('font', 'color' => 'yellow');
foreach my $item_ref ($a->content_refs_list) {
next if ref $$item_ref;
 $yellowFont->push_content($$item_ref);
}
print $yellowFont->as_HTML, "\n";
```

Which works beautifully in the sense that it creates:

```
<font color="yellow">201301022150-Job5</font>
```

But that change isn't reflected in the html document!

I'm at a loss as to how to insert the font color attribute into the original html document.

Below is my entire script.  It's a mess because I've been trying a variety of different methods without success.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::TableExtract qw(tree);
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my @jobList = ();
if ($ARGV[0]) {@jobList = $ARGV[0];} else {die ("Need list of jobs as argument\n")};

my $ddHTMLFile = "./tmp_aptg";
my $te1 = HTML::TableExtract->new( depth => 1, count => 0);
my $te2 = HTML::TableExtract->new( depth => 1, count => 1);

$te1->parse_file($ddHTMLFile);
$te2->parse_file($ddHTMLFile);

my $table1 = $te1->first_table_found;
my $table2 = $te2->first_table_found;

my $table1_tree = $table1->tree;
my $table2_tree = $table2->tree;

foreach my $a ($table1_tree->find_by_tag_name("a")) {
  my $href = $a->attr("href");
  if ($href =~ m/$jobList[0]/) {
    my $yellowFont = HTML::Element->new('font', 'color' => 'yellow');
    foreach my $item_ref ($a->content_refs_list) {
      next if ref $$item_ref;
        $yellowFont->push_content($$item_ref);
      }
    #print $yellowFont->as_HTML, "\n";
    $a->replacewith
    $a->dump;

    #my $table1_html = $table1_tree->as_HTML;
    #my $document1_tree = $te1->tree;
    #my $document1_html = $document1_tree->as_HTML;
    #my $document_html = $document1_html; 
    #print "$document_html";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time somebody uses the `<font>` tag, we have to sacrifice a [hecatomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecatomb) of [cute kittens](https://www.google.com/search?q=cute+kitten&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) to the angry webdevs that were promised *semantic markup*. A font in itself has no semantics. Instead, such things can be easily done via [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) which unsuprisingly excels at changing the color of elements.

To set the color of one element to yellow, we have to add the following code to the `style` attribute:

```
color: yellow !important;
```

Something like

```
$a->attr(style => "color: yellow !important;");
```

is likely to do the trick, although that would overwrite any previous contents. We could try to append our color to the previous contents, but we have no guarantee that the CSS already there is valid.

If the target browsers understand CSS3 (*sigh*), we could use some nice selectors to do that job for us, like

```
<style>
  table a[href~="$foo"] { color: yellow !important }
</style>
```

where `$foo` holds a sane string to be literally matched (no regexes).

Here is a data-url you can copy&paste into your address bar to see this (hopefully) working:

```
data:text/html,<style>table a[href~="foo"] { color: yellow !important }</style><table><tr><td><a href="bar">bar</a></td><td><a href="foo">foo</a></tr></table>
```

The other solution would be to create a new `<span>` element that carries the CSS, and is the sole child of the link. The former childs of `<a>` would then be childs of the `<span>`.

```
# not tested, but looks reasonable
my $span = HTML::Element->new("span", style => "...");
my @childs = $a->detach_content;
$span->push_content(@childs);
$a->push_content($span);
```

This is slightly different from the previous solution, but this difference shouldn't matter unless some advanced CSS tricks were used in the page layout.

If you really *have* to, you can adapt this solution to use font tags.
"pleease don't! can we haz `<span>`?" ← the kittens.

To see what you can do with the HTML element objects, see the [`HTML::Element` documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement).

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I can't use CSS.   The web page is created by an automated script which just pukes out HTML without any CSS linked to it and I can't add any CSS (corporate rules).  My one and only solution is editing the HTML that the script outputs.

Comment: @phileasfogg As I said, the solution for `<span>` can be easily adapted to use font tags, so that wouldn't require CSS. Basically `HTML::Element->new("font", color => "yellow")`. Please be aware that the `<font>` tag appeared in HTML 3.2, was deprecated in HTML 4.0 Transitional, and is *invalid* in HTML 4.0 Strict and later, so be sure to check the doctype first.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't read you're initial comment closely enough, sorry about that.  Thanks again for the help.